# HTML for links is being escaped in 10k tools, duplicate answers

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

In the [10k tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?flagtype=answerduplicateanswerauto) for duplicate answers, the links that show the duplicates are being escaped instead of rendered.

[image]